# Best method of adding an HTML and javascript file to Ext.Panel in Sencha touch

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Is there a simple way of including external HTML files and rendering them on an Ext.Panel in Sencha touch 2.3? Ideally I would like to create a wrapper module for an HTML file that can then be instantiated using xtype. An external javascript file should be included for handling the events on the external HTML file.

**Update:**

The files below allow keypad.html to be rendered onto the Ext.Panel in main.js.

What I would like to know is how to include the file script1.js properly so that it performs the event handling. I have tried two things:

1. Including script1.js in keypad.html. Result: it doesn't load.
2. Including script1.js in *app/index.html*. Result: it loads. However it the javascript should be loaded after keypad.html is loaded because of the way the event handlers are set up. I have tried adding body onload="myFunction()" to keypad.html and then initialising the event handlers inside this function but this doesn't work.

Furthermore, what is a simple way of returning the answer in btnOk.onclick() to app/main.js.

*app/view/main.js*

```
Ext.define('TestApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',

    config: {
        html: loadURL('resources/keypad.html'),
    }
});
```

*The loadURL function is in app/globals.js. globals.js is included in app/index.html*

```
function loadURL(url) {
    var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oRequest.open('GET', url, false);
    oRequest.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", navigator.userAgent);
    oRequest.send(null)

    return oRequest.responseText;
};
```

*app/resources/keypad.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="calculator">

    <div id="display">0</div>

    <div id="numbers">
        <div id="row1">
            <a class='r1'>1</a>
            <a class='r1'>2</a>
            <a class='r1'>3</a>
        </div>
        <div id="row2">
            <a class='r2'>4</a>
            <a class='r2'>5</a>
            <a class='r2'>6</a>
        </div>
        <div id="row3">
            <a class='r3'>7</a>
            <a class='r3'>8</a>
            <a class='r3'>9</a>
        </div>
        <div id = "row4">
            <button type="button" id="buttonCancel">Cancel</button>
            <a class='row4'>0</a>
            <button type="button" id="buttonOk">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*app/resources/script1.js*

```
window.onload = function () {

    var display = document.getElementById("display");
    var digitIndex = 0; 
    var displayTxt = "0"; 
    var numbers = document.getElementById('numbers');

    /*Called after a number has been clicked*/
    var updateNumber = function(number) {
        if (digitIndex == 0) {
            display.innerHTML = number;
            digitIndex++;
        }
        else if (digitIndex < 10) { 
            display.innerHTML += number;
            digitIndex++;
        }
    }

    /*Event handler*/
    var numberClickHandler = function(e) {
        var number = e.target.innerHTML; 
        if (e.target.id == 'buttonCancel' || e.target.id == 'buttonOk')
          return false;

        updateNumber(number);
    }

    if (numbers.addEventListener) {
      numbers.addEventListener('click', numberClickHandler, false); 
    }
    else if (numbers.attachEvent) { 
      numbers.attachEvent('onclick', numberClickHandler);
    }

    var btnCancel = document.getElementById("buttonCancel");
    btnCancel.onclick = function(event){
        display.innerHTML = "0";
        digitIndex = 0;
    }

    var btnOk = document.getElementById("buttonOk");
    btnOk.onclick = function(event){
        /*Return display.innerHTML to main.js*/
    }

};
```

Comment: Hi, could You please paste this html file

Comment: You can use a iframe inside the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe inside the panel and point the iframe src to the url of the html file.

```
var url = '<div style="height:100%;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;"><iframe style="width:100%;height:100%" src="'+url+'"/></div>';



{
xtype: 'panel',
scrollable:true,
styleHtmlContent : true,                                
html:url    
}
```